# SQL: Join table onto itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, self-join

I'm given a list of transportation lanes with a dollar amount per lane.  The problem is that sometimes an indirect route is cheaper than the direct route. I want to be able to find those instances and insert them into a new table. I've tried using a LEFT OUTER JOIN but I can't quite figure it out. Below is an example of what I'm looking for and the code I tried. *I'm not sure what database it is.*

(Edit) Example: Cost from loc. 0380 to loc. 1428 (direct) is $100.00 but cost from 0380 to 1732 and then 1428 (indirect) is $99.61.

> Org    |   Dest   |   Amount

0380 |  1428    | $100.00

0380 |  1732    | $92.26

1732 |  1428    | $7.35

---

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable 
SELECT T1.Org, T1.Dest, T1.Amount, T2.Org, T2.Dest, T2.Amount, T3.Org, T3.Dest, T3.Amount
FROM (( dbo.RateTable [T1] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RateTable [T2] 
        ON T1.Org = T2.Org) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RateTable [T3] 
        ON T1.Dest = T3.Dest AND T2.Dest = T3.Dest)
WHERE T1.Amount > (T2.Amount + T3.Amount);
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Can you provide sample data, with column edits?  (Please edit the question with this information.)

Comment: I second what Gordon said.  We need more information

Comment: @BJW . . . I'm going to make a leap and tag this sql-server.  The syntax is basically SQL Server (or perhaps Sybase).  I wanted to be sure that it is not Access, but Access doesn't support the "outer" in "left outer join".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did some digging and found this: localhost\SCGSQLEXPR2008R2. Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only change that needs to be made is in the last join condition:

```
SELECT T1.Org, T1.Dest, T1.Amount, T2.Org, T2.Dest, T2.Amount, T3.Org, T3.Dest, T3.Amount
FROM dbo.RateTable T1 JOIN
     dbo.RateTable T2
     ON T1.Org = T2.Org JOIN
     dbo.RateTable T3 
     ON T1.Dest = T3.Dest AND T2.Dest = T3.Org
----------------------------------------^
WHERE T1.Amount > (T2.Amount + T3.Amount);
```

Note that I changed the `left outer join` to regular inner joins.  The `where` condition requires matches.

This is assuming that "Org" standard for "Origin" or something like that.

Comment: Yes, Org = Orign and Dest = Destination.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following simple selection?  Can it be simplified as such where the calcamount is the calculated amount you need.
Select (CASE WHEN CalcAmount1 > CalcAmount2 THEN Amount1  ELSE Amount2 END) 
from Table